# change the first letter of value of an array to uppercase

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$arr = array ('name'=>'bunt','game'=>'battlefield','fame'=>'hero');

foreach ($arr as $key=>$val){
  $val = ucfirst($val);
}

var_dump($arr);
// result would be
// 'name' => 'Bunt', 'game' => 'Battlefield', 'fame' => 'Hero'
```

I am missing something here.... How to accomplish this ?

Comment: Just to note what is going on here so you understand, each time your foreach loop is run it overwrites the $val variable. It doesn't get saved anywhere, and when the loop is finished the last $val is retained but just floats in the ether doing nothing, alone, with no-one to love.

Comment: if you want to do it this way, you would go $arr[$key]=ucfirst($val); because $val is a copy and not a reference to the original value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$new_array = array_map('ucfirst', $arr);
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/glZmC3)

Answer (score 2):

`$val` is just a temporary variable in each iteration. To update the value of each key you need to pass it as a reference. Do this.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => &$val) {
    $val = ucfirst($val);
}
```

Notice the `&` following `$val`.

[Here's](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) some documentation on references in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

foreach ($arr as $key=>&$val){
  $val = ucfirst($val);
}

Put an & sign before $val . that will make it reference the variable instead of assigning the value.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the key to access the array?

```
<?php
$arr = array('name' => 'bunt', 'game' => 'battlefield');

foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    $arr[$key] = ucfirst($val);
}

var_dump($arr);
```